# Create minutely date_time range for fixed hours intervals during certain days using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, date-range

I have a dataframe with has `900` rows, I need to create a `date` column from `2021-01-01` to `2021-01-15`, for each day, only hours from `10:00:00` to `12:00:00`, the interval is `2 minutes`,

The expected result will like this: `2021-01-01 10:02:00, 2021-01-01 10:04:00, ..., 2021-01-01 12:00:00, 2021-01-02 10:02:00, ..., 2021-01-02 12:00:00, ..., 2021-01-15 12:00:00`.

My trial code:

```
df['date'] = pd.date_range(datetime(2021, 1, 1, hour=10, minute=2), periods=900, freq='2min')
```

Out:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01 10:02:00', '2021-01-01 10:04:00',
               '2021-01-01 10:06:00', '2021-01-01 10:08:00',
               '2021-01-01 10:10:00', '2021-01-01 10:12:00',
               '2021-01-01 10:14:00', '2021-01-01 10:16:00',
               '2021-01-01 10:18:00', '2021-01-01 10:20:00',
               ...
               '2021-01-02 15:42:00', '2021-01-02 15:44:00',
               '2021-01-02 15:46:00', '2021-01-02 15:48:00',
               '2021-01-02 15:50:00', '2021-01-02 15:52:00',
               '2021-01-02 15:54:00', '2021-01-02 15:56:00',
               '2021-01-02 15:58:00', '2021-01-02 16:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=900, freq='2T')
```

Obviously, it's not as expected, how could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Create a `date_range` then use [`between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html).

Comment: Since it `60` rows each day during 15 days, total 900 rows, so i think it should start at `10:02:00` for each day.

Comment: That's ok if you intended to be so  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of specifying the `periods=` parameter, you can set `start=` and `end=` parameters in [`pd.date_range()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and then use [`.between_time()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start=datetime(2021, 1, 1, hour=10), end=datetime(2021, 1, 15, hour=12), freq='2min')})
df = df.set_index('date')
date_range = df.between_time('10:02:00', '12:00:00')
print(date_range)

date
2021-01-01 10:02:00
2021-01-01 10:04:00
2021-01-01 10:06:00
2021-01-01 10:08:00
...
2021-01-15 11:52:00
2021-01-15 11:54:00
2021-01-15 11:56:00
2021-01-15 11:58:00
2021-01-15 12:00:00
900 rows × 0 columns
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(datetime(2021, 1, 1, hour=10, minute=2), periods=900, freq='2min'), 
                   'Val':[i for i in range(900)]})

df = df.set_index('Date')

result = df.between_time('10:00:00', '12:00:00')

result.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 121 entries, 2021-01-01 10:02:00 to 2021-01-02 12:00:00
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   Val     121 non-null    int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 1.9 KB
```

Comment: emm, seems the result is not as expected, the last row's date should be `2021-01-15 12:00:00` instead of `2021-01-02 12:00:00`, since there are `60` rows for each day.